# vmstat: Very high interrupts (system.in) & context switches (system.cs)

Tags: vmstat

My desktop PC has been quite sluggish lately, especially after I leave it overnight and then start using it again the next morning. I've tried decreasing swappiness (current value is 5) and the disk activity is now less intense. But the sluggishness remains. `vmstat 1` output is something like:

```
procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu--------
 r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st
 2  0      1214672      1325428       100660      2065148    0    0     0     0  793 3396   7   2  92   0   0
 3  0      1214672      1329396       100660      2067812    0    0     0     0  916 5294   9   1  90   0   0
 2  0      1214672      1330884       100660      2065156    0    0     0     0  756 3759   4   2  93   0   0
 2  0      1214672      1320344       100676      2065260    0    0     0  3056  764 4351   8   2  89   1   0
 0  0      1214672      1328776       100676      2065260    0    0     0     0  850 4005   3   1  95   0   0
 0  0      1214672      1331256       100676      2065260    0    0     0     0  890 4519   5   3  92   0   0
 0  0      1214672      1324560       100676      2067920    0    0     0    52  674 3485   6   2  93   0   0
 2  0      1214672      1322080       100676      2065260    0    0    16     0  874 5058   9   3  88   0   0
 0  0      1214672      1323816       100684      2065364    0    0    44  1740 1453 16016   8   4  88   0   0
```

Hundreds and sometimes thousands of interrupts, tens of thousands even >100k context switches are often encountered. Merely moving mouse pointer around rather quickly will make the context switches shoot to the roof, especially if I point the mouse to the Task Manager area in the panel. I'm using KDE Plasma (KDE Frameworks 5.35.0, Linux Mint 18.2).

If I use another desktop environment like Cinnamon, the context switches numbers are not nearly as high (usually mid-hundreds when idle, or around 1000-2000 when more active). But I prefer Plasma to other desktop environments.

How to find out the cause of the problem in more details and remedy it?